# Align text in middle of box using drawstring

Tags: c#, xna

How do I align text in the middle of a box? My attempt, with pseudo code for how I am trying to do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfBoxes; i++)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(Box[i], BoxPosition[i], Color.White);
    Vector2 Offset = new Vector2("BoxNumber[i].ToString().LengthOfString" / 2, "BoxNumber[i].ToString().HeightOfString" / 2);
    spriteBatch.DrawString(TimingScreenFont, BoxNumber[i].ToString(), BoxPosition[i]+Offset, Color.Black);
}
```

I can't find anywhere how to measure the pixel length /height of a string. I'm also not sure at all if this is the best way to do it.
The box number can be anything from 0 to 999, and the box is only just bigger than the number so it's very noticeable if it's off-centre

Answer (score 1):

You can use MeasureString to measure your text. You could then do a bit of maths and centre it.

```
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, TimingScreenFont);
```

Another possible option is to use

```
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

spriteBatch.DrawString(BoxNumber[i].ToString(), TimingScreenFont, BoxPosition[i]+Offset, Color.Black, stringFormat);
```

Comment: Hmmm, StringFormat seems to be the way forward here, but why do I get this error: 

     The type or namespace name 'StringFormat' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I assume you have System.Drawing.dll referenced?

Comment: No I don't. How do I do that? I've just googled it and can't find the answer. I've tried adding a reference in the solution explorer from the .NET tab but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user2056166 what kind of VS project is it?

Comment: c#, using VS2010 with XNA

Answer (score 1):

As *geedubb* said you should use `MeasureString`, but I think you'll only need `SpriteFont.MeasureString`.

Something like:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(TimingScreenFont,  
   BoxNumber[i].ToString(),  
   BoxPosition[i] + Offset, //this should be the center of your box
   Color.Black, 
   0, 
   SpriteFont.MeasureString(BoxNumber[i].ToString()) / 2, //center of the string
   1,
   SpriteEffects.None,
   0
);
```